# How to hide title of navigation bar keeping back button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

How can I hide the title of the nav bar but keep the back button with the word "Back" on it? I noticed that in objective-c when I don't set a title for the navigation controller, the back button does not show up. I would like to hide the title (because I use a custom background), and keep the back button with the word "Back".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the back button is set on the navigation item of the view controller that is pushed onto the stack *before* the current one, not on the navigation item of the current controller. This is somewhat non-intuitive.

In the interface builder go to the view to which the back button leads, select its navigation item or add a new one, go to the "Back" button property, and enter the text that you would like to appear on the back button. Now go to the controller where you would like to have no title, and erase the text in the "Title" property of its navigation item.